# Referencing data from another workbook in an array

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently using the below code to define an array from the active workbook

```
Dim MyRangeArray As Variant


MyRangeArray = Array(Sheet1.Range("A4:N19"), Sheet2.Range("A4:N19"))
```

I want this array to reference data from another workbook instead of the workbook which has the code. The result i am looking for is:

```
MyRangeArray= Array(Wb1.sheets.RangeX,wb2.sheets.rangeX)
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you are using sheet Code Names, which will reference sheets in the book containing the code, irrespective of if that book is active.

To reference a different workbook, again irrespective of if it's active, create references to the workbook and worksheet objects

```
Dim MyRangeArray As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb = Application.Workbooks("NameOfWorkbook.xlsx")
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("NameOfSheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("NameOfSheet2")
MyRangeArray = Array(ws1.Range("RangeAddress1").Value, ws2.Range("RangeAddress2").Value)
```

Comment: you may add a reference to `wb` as an example, too

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error by doing the following:

Dim r1,r2 as range

r1=ws1.Range("RangeAddress1")
r2=ws2.Range("RangeAddress2")

Mrangearray=array(r1,r2)